# Check if values counting correctly

Tags: excel

I have the following simple excel spreadsheet:

```
         A         B            C
1        1
2        2
3        3
4        4
5        5
```

In column A I just entered numbers 1 to 5.
Now I am looking for a formula that checks if column A always counts down correctly. For example it can happen that the user overtypes the number 4 in row 4 so the following structure appears:

```
         A         B            C
1        1
2        2
3        3
4        3
5        5
```

In cell B1 I would like to insert now a formula that gives an alert in case this happens.

Do you have any idea what formular I can use for this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

in B2 write:

```
=IF(A2=A1+1;"ok";"error")
```

and auto fill next cells of column B

Answer (score 0):

You can use

```
=IF(A2=A1+1;"TRUE";"FALSE")
```

Or if it should be according to the row

```
=IF(ROW()=A1;"TRUE";"FALSE")
```

Autofill accordingly